# Merge Similar Strings Python

Tags: python, regex, string, text, nlp

I'm having two strings

```
string1 = "apple banna kiwi mango"
string2 = "aple banana mango lemon"
```

I want the resultant of addition of these two strings (not concatenation) i.e. result should look like

```
result = "apple banana kiwi mango lemon"
```

My current approach is rather simple.

1. Tokenize the multiline string (the above strings are after tokenization), remove any noises (special/ newline characters/ empty strings)
2. The next step is to identify the cosine similarity of the strings, if it is above 0.9, then I add one of the string to final result

Now, here is the problem. It doesn't cover the part where one string contains one half of a word and other contains the other half (or correct word in some cases) of word. I have also added [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46860908/concatenate-two-strings-with-a-common-substring) function in my script. But again the problem remains. Any help on how to move forward with this is appreciated.

```
def text_to_vector(text):
     words = WORD.findall(text)
     return Counter(words)

def get_cosine(vec1, vec2):
     intersection = set(vec1.keys()) & set(vec2.keys())
     numerator = sum([vec1[x] * vec2[x] for x in intersection])

     sum1 = sum([vec1[x]**2 for x in vec1.keys()])
     sum2 = sum([vec2[x]**2 for x in vec2.keys()])
     denominator = math.sqrt(sum1) * math.sqrt(sum2)

     if not denominator:
        return 0.0
     else:
        return float(numerator) / denominator


def merge_string(string1, string2):
    i = 0
    while not string2.startswith(string1[i:]):
        i += 1

    sFinal = string1[:i] + string2
    return sFinal

for item in c:
for j in d:
    vec1 = text_to_vector(item)
    vec2 = text_to_vector(j)
    r = get_cosine(vec1, vec2)
    if r > 0.5:
        if r > 0.85:
            final.append(item)
            break
        else:
            sFinal = merge_string(item, j)
            #print("1.", len(sFinal), len(item), len(j))
            if len(sFinal) >= len(item) + len(j) -8:
                sFinal = merge_string(j, item)
                final.append(sFinal)
                #print("2.", len(sFinal), len(item), len(j))
                temp.append([item, j])
                break
```

Comment: Great Idea! What have you tried?

Comment: I have mentioned my approach. Do you need the code as well?

Comment: @JackDaniels yes, you need to show us what you've tried already.

Comment: Ok, let me update.

Comment: I don't think there is a proper way to do this without having either a dictionary of correctly spelled words, or more than two lists, so you could apply some kind of "majority vote" for which variant to pick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difficult part is to check if the word is a valid English word.

For this either you have to have a dictionary to check the word against, or use
nltk.

```
     pip install nltk  

     from nltk.corpus import wordnet  

     set([w for w in (string1 + string2).split() if  wordnet.synsets(w)]) 

     Out[41]: {'apple', 'banana', 'kiwi', 'lemon', 'mango'}
```

To catch digits, if present, add isdigit().

```
st1 = 'Includes Og Added Sugars'

st2 = 'Includes 09 Added Sugars 09'


set([w for w in (st1 + st2).split() if  (wordnet.synsets(w) or w.isdigit())])

Out[30]: {'09', 'Added', 'Includes', 'Sugars'}
```

To catch abbreviations like g, mg add re.match().

```
set([w for w in (st1 + st2).split() if  (wordnet.synsets(w) or w.isdigit() or re.match(r'\d+g|mg',w))])

Out[40]: {'09', '0g', 'Added', 'Includes', 'Sugars'}
```

Comment: This seems to be (close to) the right approach, but the result is odd. You never "fix" `w`, so how are there two "banana" in the result, and where is the second correctly spelled "mango"?

Comment: @tobias_k. Thank you for your comment. I missed repeating words.. Changing to set, does it...

Comment: I'll try this. I have already tried symspell but that didn't help much. But will give it a shot, and will update here.

Comment: @LetzerWille It doesn't seem to work. Like in this case ['Includes Og Added Sugars/', 'Includes 09 Added Sugars 09'], the combination doesn't seem to work. Also I need the resultant in order as it is. I was hoping for more of a dynamic solution rather than a static. I have tried [symspell](https://github.com/mammothb/symspellpy) for correction, but didn't work as well. Anyways, not looking for a correction as such, just need the final output as in the example in question above.

Comment: @JackDaniels, it worked for me. st1 = 'Includes Og Added Sugars'
st2 = 'Includes 09 Added Sugars 09'
set([w for w in (st1 + st2).split() if  wordnet.synsets(w)])
Out[22]: {'Added', 'Includes', 'Sugars'}

Comment: @LetzerWille it covered only the text, say I have some numbers as well in the string. I need a resultant of both strings (and not just for text).

Comment: @JackDaniels, just add isdigit() set([w for w in (st1 + st2).split() if  (wordnet.synsets(w) or w.isdigit())])
Out[30]: {'09', 'Added', 'Includes', 'Sugars'}

Comment: This seems the closest I have come. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever heard of Levenshtein's distance? I suggest the following algorithm:

1. Split the lists into elements (string1.split(" "))
2. Loop through `list(string1)`. Inside it loop through `list(string2)` and if Levenshtein's distance for the two elements is say, less than 3, push the element to the result array.
3. Return `result`.

`for i in list(string1):
        for k in list(string2):
            if levenshtein(i,k) < 3:
                res.append(i)`

Comment: I tried this as well as soundex. But thing is which word should I push, pushing the bigger word of two is not always the answer here.